# Can I use typescript definitions in graphql queries?

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo

Right now I am doing this:

```
import { comment } from "forms";

const QUERY_COMMENTS = gql`
  query QUERY_COMMENTS($projectId:Int! $orderBy:CommentOrderByInput) {
    comments(projectId:$projectId orderBy:$orderBy) {
      ${comment}
    }
  }
`;
```

---

```
export const comment = `
    id
    text
    date
    postedBy {
        id
        name
    }
`;
```

---

```
interface comment {
     id:number,
     text:string,
     date:string,
     postedBy: {
       id:number,
       name:string,
     },
   }
```

I basically repeat myself.
IMO it should be possible and be very useful to use typescript definitions in graphql-queries.
Yet I did not find a way to do it.

Comment: Typescript definitions get erased when you transpile your code into JS, so no, you can't use them in any way at runtime

Comment: Maybe [type-graphql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/type-graphql) is worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [graphql-zeus](https://github.com/graphql-editor/graphql-zeus).

this library generates typescript definitions from **api** and gives you some method to use for queries and mutations.
methods are using definitions that i mentioned, so you are **typesafe**.

Answer (score 1):

From the tags on your question, it looks like you're using the Apollo ecosystem. So i'd looking into their codegen support: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling#code-generation